# How to convert mysql query into acceptable c# string?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

Im creating columns using mysql dynamically if column doesnt exist.. I got the code which works in mysql console but when it comes to c# its giving me "Fatal encountered during command execution"

```
SET @preparedStatement = (SELECT IF(
(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE  table_name = 'tableName'
    AND table_schema = DATABASE()
    AND column_name = 'colName'
) > 0,
"SELECT 1",
"ALTER TABLE `tableName` ADD `colName` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0';"
));

PREPARE alterIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement;
EXECUTE alterIfNotExists;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists;
```

above code i converted into c# string as

```
string qry = "SET @preparedStatement = ( SELECT IF( (SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'attendance' AND TABLE_NAME = '" + tname + "' AND COLUMN_NAME = '" + code + "_C' ) > 0, \"SELECT 1', \"ALTER TABLE " + tname + " ADD " + code + "_C int(3) NOT NULL default '0'; \" )); PREPARE alterIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement; EXECUTE alterIfNotExists; DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists;";
```

what's the error getting?

Execution Code:

```
    private void columnCreate_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tname = "bca_i"; //for temprory
        string code = "BCAXX";//for temprory
        string qry = @"SET @preparedStatement = ( SELECT IF( (SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'attendance' AND TABLE_NAME = '" + tname + "' AND COLUMN_NAME = '" + code + "_C' ) > 0, \"SELECT 1', \"ALTER TABLE " + tname + " ADD " + code + "_C int(3) NOT NULL default '0'; \" )); PREPARE alterIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement; EXECUTE alterIfNotExists; DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists;";
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConStr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(qry, conn))
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: try this:
string qry = @"SET @preparedStatement = ( SELECT IF( (SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'attendance' AND TABLE_NAME = '" + tname + "' AND COLUMN_NAME = '" + code + "_C' ) > 0, \"SELECT 1', \"ALTER TABLE " + tname + " ADD " + code + "_C int(3) NOT NULL default '0'; \" )); PREPARE alterIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement; EXECUTE alterIfNotExists; DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists;";

Comment: Thanks but its same error

Comment: show us your execution code.

Comment: i have edited my question with execution code

Comment: why dont you write a stored procedure.

Comment: Im not much familiar with procedures. Can u guide me with this. I wanted to create a table if it doesnt exists when i searched i got the above code. but im getting Error

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html follow this

Comment: I am not geeting how to do it. Can u help me with it. Im just a beginner tried to create procedure but couldnt

Answer (score 0):

The part

```
\"SELECT 1', \"A
```

does not match your original query at

```
"SELECT 1",
"A
```

Do you spot it? You replaced the `"` after `1` by an `'`.

Comment: Yes but its not the problem i replaced again same error

Answer (score 0):

I just figured other way for checking column exist.. Just used below query and checked if the column exists iterating through the loop of columns

```
string last_col = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'attendance' AND TABLE_NAME ='" + subCodeText.Text + "'";
```

where `attendance` is database and `subCodeText.Text` is my table name.